# CakePHP3 - require autoload failed to open stream, no such file or directory

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

After deploying my CakePHP3 project to Ubuntu 14.04 server when I open project in browser I get this error:

> Warning: require(/var/www/html/xyz-web/vendor/autoload.php): failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/html/xyz-web/config/bootstrap.php on line 38
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '/var/www/html/xyz-web/vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /var/www/html/xyz-web/config/bootstrap.php on line 38

And if I run `bin/cake server` inside that directory (on the server) I get next output:

> Warning: require(/var/www/html/xyz-web/vendor/autoload.php): failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/html/xyz-web/config/bootstrap.php on line 38 PHP Fatal error:
>   require(): Failed opening required
>   '/var/www/html/xyz-web/vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /var/www/html/xyz-web/config/bootstrap.php on line 38
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '/var/www/html/xyz-web/vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /var/www/html/xyz-web/config/bootstrap.php on line 38

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by installing composer on the server and running it inside a project.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install curl php5-cli git && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

and then `cd` to cake project (`cd /var/www/html/{project_name}`) and run `composer install` to install required packages.